# How to debug Android databinding when build fails with `error: Cannot resolve type 'someType'`?

Tags: android, data-binding, android-databinding

Unfortunately I came across this issue quite often already.
In my Android project I am using `databinding` to bind classes to my xml layouts which works fine. Basically I am doing it the following way:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <data>
    <variable name="myClass" type="com.somepackagename.myClass" />
  </data>
</layout>
```

Throughout my (quite large) project, i am frequently using the same `variable name` for many different xml layouts.

After doing a lot of refactoring, I can now no longer build my project due to the following build error:

```
e: error: Cannot resolve type 'myClass'
e: error: cannot generate view binders android.databinding.tool.util.LoggedErrorException:       failure, see logs for details.
Cannot resolve type 'myClass'
    at android.databinding.tool.util.L.printMessage(L.java:134)
    at android.databinding.tool.util.L.e(L.java:107)
    at android.databinding.tool.expr.Expr.getResolvedType(Expr.java:386)
    at android.databinding.tool.expr.ExprModel.lambda$resolveTypes$1(ExprModel.java:618)
 ...
```

While the errorMessage is clear to me and tells me which variable name is causing this issue, unfortunately it is not very verbose and does not tell me:

- which xml file causes this problem
- which specific type causes this problem

This makes it extremely hard to find the causing issue if you've changed many xml layout.

Isn't there a better way to debug such errors?

Answer (score 5):

After spending many hours, I finally found out what was causing the issue.
I found a way to debug such errors in a way that one should always find the issue relatively quickly. The setup however for this takes quite a few steps though:

First of all, I want to thank the author of this excellent article who gave me a good idea where to start:
https://medium.com/@dzolnai/debugging-a-databinding-compiler-error-9510f88f4cec

Based on the above article, here is how you should be able to find the causing error quickly.

1. Add a new configuration in Android Studio: Edit → Run configurations. Give it an arbitrary name, for instance `DatabindingDebugging` and click OK (i.e. nothing should be changed)
2. In a terminal window execute: `./gradlew assembleDebug --no-daemon -Dorg.gradle.debug=true -Dkotlin.compiler.execution.strategy="in-process" -Dkotlin.daemon.jvm.options="-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket\,server=y\,suspend=n\,address=5005"`. The build should print `> Starting Daemon`. I.e. it waits until you debug.
3. Back in Android Studio, on the top section your new configuration `DatabindingDebugging`should be selected. Click the green debug icon `Debug DatabindingDebugging` or press `Ctrl + D`
4. The debug window should now launch and indicate something like `Connected to the target VM...`.
   In the meantime, back in your terminal window, the gradle build should now execute as usual.
5. In the debug window in Android Studio, manually add a new Breakpoint: Click ViewBreakpoints (red icon with 2 dots). In the Breakpoints window add a new Breakpoint by clicking the `+` icon on the top left and select `1. Java Method Breakpoints`
6. In the pop up enter the following:
   `Class pattern: android.databinding.tool.util.L` | `Method name: printMessage` and click OK.
7. Make sure that both the `Enabled` and `Suspend` checkbox are checked. Also make sure to check the `Condition` checkbox and enter the following expression: `kind.name.equals("ERROR")`. This way we instruct the debugger to only suspend if the databinding tool prints a log message with an error.
8. Click Done.
9. At some point during your build, if you have a databinding `ERROR`, a breakpoint should be reached. In the debugger you should now see the exact error message the logger printed: `Cannot resolve type 'someType'`
10. Now scroll down the Stacktrace on the left pane of the debug window and click the entry `getResolvedType:386, Expr`. On the right pane you should now see the causing type for the error: `this.mUserDefinedType = "com.somepackagename.myClass"`.
11. The final step is easy. Using Android Studio, simply search for this class, for instance using: Edit → Find → Find in Path → "com.somepackagename.myClass". On the right side of the window, select File mask: `*.xml` You should now see all xml files that caused the issue.

Hope this helps someone in the future. Still IMO this is way to complicated. If anyone knows a better way to debug such issues, please let me know :)